# Array Not Reading From a File Correctly

Tags: java, arrays

I'm attempting to read in some lines from a text file ("puzzle.txt") and save them into a 2D array as part of a wordsearch problem.  The first eleven lines look like this:

```
10 10
WVERTICALL
ROOAFFLSAB
ACRILIATOA
NDODKONWDC
DRKESOODDK
OEEPZEGLIW
MSIIHOAERA
ALRKRRIRER
KODIDEDRCD
HELWSLEUTH
```

The first two integers (R and C) are the number of rows and columns, and are both reading in correctly.  The rest of it, however, isn't working.  When I try to print out lines 2-10 as a string, all I get is:

```
[ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ]
```

... and so on.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.io.File;

public class WordSearch {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("puzzle.txt"));

        /* Creating a 2D array of size R x C, variables in puzzle.txt 
        specifying the number of rows and the number of columns 
        respectively, and putting the next R lines of puzzle.txt into 
        that array. */

        // Reading in variables R and C from puzzle.txt
        int R = sc.nextInt();
        int C = sc.nextInt();

        // Initializing array of size R x C
        char[][] grid = new char[R][C];


        String s = sc.nextLine();


        for (int i=0;i<R;i++) {

            for (int j=0;j<C;j++) {

                grid[j] = s.toCharArray();

                System.out.print(Arrays.toString(grid[j]));

            }

        }

    }
```

I'm new to Java, so I'm guessing the problem is extremely obvious to those of you with more experience.  Help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
char[][] grid = new char[R][];
sc.nextLine(); // flush the line containing R and C
for (int i=0;i<R;i++) {
    grid[i] = sc.nextLine().toCharArray();         // char array of size C
    System.out.print(Arrays.toString(grid[i]));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you for got to add:

```
s = sc.nextLine();
```

before

```
grid[i] = s.toCharArray();
```

Remeber add it before. get rid of the inner loop.